# Invoke Paho MQTT from a CPP file

Tags: c++, linker, mqtt, paho

I have a sample.cpp file from which MQTT client is invoked which is in another file

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

extern "C" {
     #include "pub.c"
}


int main() 
{       
   payload = 1111  
   sendMQTT(payload)  
}
```

The pub.c file is as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "MQTTClient.h"

void sendMQTT(int payload){

     MQTTClient client;
     MQTTClient_connectOptions conn_opts = MQTTClient_connectOptions_initializer;
     MQTTClient_message pubmsg = MQTTClient_message_initializer;
     MQTTClient_deliveryToken token;
     MQTTClient_create(&client, "tcp://mqtt1.mindlogic.com:1883", "ExampleClientPub",MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_NONE, NULL);
}
```

when i run the sample.cpp file using the command,

```
g++ sample.cpp
```

Can someone help me out what the issue is here?

I get the following error,

```
undefined reference to `MQTTClient_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is paho library i have used https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.cpp

Comment: Have you looked at the options you can pass to the `g++` command? What exactly do you expect that command to do?

Comment: When i run the command, it should send the payload from sample.cpp to pub.c file and send data through MQTT.

Comment: `g++` is a compiler, it won't do anything except compile source code to machine code (and with the right options link it with other existing libraries)

Comment: At this point it's probably worth pointing out that C++ is not an interpreted language (like nodejs or python). You need to compile/link the source code into a binary that you can then run. `g++` is the compiler, not the interpreter